# Determine the value, in degrees, of x in the quadrilateral below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure below, $AB = BC$. Determine the value, in degrees, of x ($Answer:10^o$)

[image]

The solution I found was

[image]

$3x = x+20 \implies x = 10^o$

How to prove that the $\angle DBE=20^o$?

Comment: You see, if $E$ is constructed such that $\angle BEC=3x$, then $BE=BC=AB$. Therefore $\triangle ABE$ is isosceles with base $AE$. Draw perpendiculars $BA_1, BE_1$ from $B$ to the sides $DA$ and $DE$. The right-angled triangles $ABA_1$ and $EBE_1$ have the hypotenuse and a side equal. So, they are congruent. Therefore, $\angle ABA_1=\angle EBE_1$. The triangles $\triangle DBA_1$ and $\triangle DBE_1$ are also congruent. The angles that you want to prove are both $20$ are subtraction of two pairs of equal angles in these triangles.

Comment: @NDB How can you assume that $BC = AB \text{ or }BE = BA$
I suspect the creator of the exercise got sloppy.  I think we're supposed to assume it's a trapezoid.  In that case, because the top and bottom are parallel we can infer $\angle BDC = \angle DBA$ which makes $x=20$.

Comment: @nickalh By reading the very first sentence and $BE$ is constructed to have that property. You are the one pulling assumptions out of thin air, like "top and bottom are parallel". That is not given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, but we can somewhat more easily finish by just handling things in the opposite order (although, as I indicate below, there are actually $2$ possible answers). Similar to what you've shown, draw $BE$ just so that $\measuredangle DBE=20^{\circ}$. Then we also have $\measuredangle DAB = \measuredangle DEB = 160^{\circ} - x$, which means the $3$ angles in $\triangle DAB$ match those in $\triangle DEB$. Thus, since $DB$ is a common side, its side length is the same for both triangles, so we get

$$\triangle DAB \cong \triangle DEB \;\;\to\;\; \lvert AB \rvert = \lvert BE \rvert$$

With it being given that $\lvert AB \rvert = \lvert BC \rvert$, this means $\lvert BE \rvert = \lvert BC \rvert$. However, next note that, based on just the provided information, without assuming the figure is necessarily a particularly accurate representation, there are now actually $3$ possibilities to check (although just something like stating $\measuredangle DBC$ is $\gt 20^{\circ}$ or that it's obtuse, would have been sufficient for there to be only the first possibility below).

First, if $E$ is to the left of $C$ (i.e., in $DC$, as shown in your figure), then $\triangle BEC$ is isosceles. Thus, by also using your results, we then have that

$$\measuredangle BEC = 3x \;\;\to\;\; 3x = x + 20^{\circ} \;\;\to\;\; x = 10^{\circ}$$

The second possibility  is that $E$ is actually the same point as $C$. In this case, we get from the angles in $\triangle BED$ that

$$\measuredangle BED = 3x \;\;\to\;\; x + 3x + 20^{\circ} = 180^{\circ} \;\;\to\;\; x = 40^{\circ}$$

The final, third possibility to consider is that $E$ is to the right of $C$, i.e., those $2$ points are basically switched around in your diagram. We would then have $\measuredangle BCE = \measuredangle BEC = 180^{\circ}-3x$. Then using the sum of angles in $\triangle DEB$ gives that

$$x + (180^{\circ}-3x) + 20^{\circ} = 180^{\circ} \;\;\to\;\; -2x + 20^{\circ} = 0 \;\;\to\;\; x = 10^{\circ}$$

On the other hand, since $0^{\circ} \lt \measuredangle CBE \lt 20^{\circ}$, we get from $\triangle CBE$ that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
180^{\circ} & \gt 2(180^{\circ}-3x) \gt 160^{\circ} \\
180^{\circ} & \gt 360^{\circ}-6x \gt 160^{\circ} \\
-180^{\circ} & \gt -6x \gt -200^{\circ} \\
30^{\circ} & \lt x \lt \frac{100}{3}^{\circ} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

However, this contradicts the previous equation's result, so this third possibility is not a valid case.

Comment: Thank my friend

Answer (score 3):

The cicumdiameter of $\triangle BAD$ is $\frac{AB}{\sin(x)}$. The cicumdiameter of $\triangle BCD$ is $\frac{BC}{\sin(x)}$. These are equal since $AB=BC$.

Since $BD$ is a chord of both the circumcircle of $\triangle BAD$ and the circumcircle of $\triangle BCD$, we get that either $\angle BAD=\angle BCD$ or $\angle BAD=180^{\large\circ}-\angle BCD$. That is, there are two solutions.

---

Solution 1: $\angle BAD=\color{#C00}{\angle BCD}$.

Since the angles in $\triangle BAD$ sum to $180^{\large\circ}$,
$$
x+\color{#C00}{3x}+20^{\large\circ}=180^{\large\circ}\implies x=40^{\large\circ}\tag1
$$
[image]

$\triangle BAD$ and $\triangle BCD$ are both $20^{\large\circ}{-}120^{\large\circ}{-}40^{\large\circ}$.

---

Solution 2: $\angle BAD=\color{#C00}{180^{\large\circ}-\angle BCD}$.

Since the angles in $\triangle BAD$ sum to $180^{\large\circ}$,
$$
x+\color{#C00}{180^{\large\circ}-3x}+20^{\large\circ}=180^{\large\circ}\implies x=10^{\large\circ}\tag2
$$
[image]

$\triangle BAD$ is $20^{\large\circ}{-}150^{\large\circ}{-}10^{\large\circ}$ and $\triangle BCD$ is $140^{\large\circ}{-}30^{\large\circ}{-}10^{\large\circ}$.

Solution 2 is the one found in the question.

Comment: Thanks for help